TVS Diode Identification
Can someone help he identify this TVS Diode?  I'm sure it's made by Vishay.


If it's made by Vishay, why does it have the Littelfuse logo?

@nanash1 Truthfully, I thought it was a sidewards F or LL nearly surrounded by a box shape. Littelfuse's corporate logo would have made it less dubious since it has a small lightning bolt in the logo. I haven't seen this logo on their products that are not TVS diodes. But I would agree that it's definitely not Vishay.

It's a Littelfuse SMBJ24CA TVS diode.

Here is a picture from LCSC to confirm the marking style:

